# php SQL insert results empty entries in database.

Tags: php, mysql, forms

When I submit the form, I get a success message however the data is missing from the database, the entries are blank..

Basically the problem is with in the $sql string.

The sql string will VALUES echo fine, however entries are blank in the database.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$name = (string)$_POST["name"];
$email = (string)$_POST["email"];
$phone = (string)$_POST["phone"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (name,email,phone)
VALUES ('{$name}','{$email}','{$phone}')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: This looks very SQL-injectable.  What's the actual runtime value of `$sql` when you execute it?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for the form?  Did you set its method to POST?  Have you tried printing $_POST, $name, $email, and/or $phone to see if they contain what you think they do?  Perhaps just change the success message to `echo "Created record ('{$name}','{$email}','{$phone}')";` to check, and/or add an `echo "POST Data: " . print_r($_POST,true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the quotes to literals ' and added id to each form field, I also removed the (string)CAST Now it works.

**PHP:**

```
    $name =$_POST['name'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];
    $phone =$_POST['phone'];
```

**HTML:**

```
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name:"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email:"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number:"/><br/>
```